# Array to string conversion error when trying to update a register in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, mariadb

I'm querying one specific register in a db table named 'interesteds', and trying to update some of its fields (not all), but I get this error:

```
Array to string conversion (SQL: update `interesteds` set `updated_at` = 2017-10-04 00:47:00, `address` = adf, `branch` = gaf, `types` = afva, `means` = mail, `flux` = asvas, `size` = sfvfd where `id` = 38)
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    public function postInterestedDetails()
{
    $details = request()->only(['address', 'branch', 'types', 'means', 'flux', 'size']);
    $email = request()->only(['email']);
    $interested = Interested::where('email', $email)->first()->fill($details);
    $updated = $interested->save();
    return $updated;

}
```

If I ask for " return $interested " I can get the updated register, but when I try to save it the array to string error appears. The "protected $fillable" is properly set in the model file. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you change   $email = request()->only(['email']); to   $email =request()->email;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `request()->only(['email']);` return any array so where condtion will fail

So if you change  `$email = request()->only(['email']);` to  `$email = request()->email;` Then it will works fine

Updated
As per your dump result  `means` is an array

```
"means" => array:1 [▼ 0 => "mail" ]
```

so you can update like this

```
$details = request()->only(['address', 'branch', 'types', 'flux', 'size']);
$details['means']=implode(",",request()->means);
```

Comment: You were right I was getting the mail in an array but that didn´t solve the problem, the same error persists :(

Comment: Yes, here it is:     array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "XfmeAa4ASQr5P6FantmPyo971Vbb7qtOEQ6fxqMa"
  "email" => "ruben@1startup.co"
  "address" => "hello"
  "branch" => "these"
  "types" => "are"
  "means" => array:1 [▶]
  "flux" => "example"
  "size" => "inputs"
]

Comment: Thank you, I got an error with $details->means=implode(",",request()->means); but then I replaced it by $details['means'] = implode(",", $details['means']); and it worked fine! :)